# What folders are indexed / covered by 'locate'

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, locate

On OS X, I think the locate DB is populated by running:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

But locate does not seem to find anything in or below ~/

Should locate.updatedb be indexing my home folder by default? If so, any suggestions or ideas why it is not? If it doesn't index ~/ by default, are there any reasons to not index this folder hierarchy? If not, how do I configure it to do so?

---

Also, when I run locate.updatedb from ~/ (as non-root) it works. When I run it from anything below (for example, ~/Desktop/) I get the following errors:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
find: .: Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you use FileVault?

Comment: Nope I do not use FileVault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locate runs as the "nobody" user to prevent other users from being able to see "your" files in the locate database. As *your* account is the only one with permission to explore your files, locate can't see them. Even if your account is the sole local user, this limitation applies.
When you `sudo` the locate.updatedb script, the `find` command it spawns is specifically started as unprivileged.  While you could modify the script to prevent this issue, I can't say it's recommended.

Also, locate is not enabled by default as it is presumes Spotlight/MDS are better for most people.  I'd suggest trying out the mdfind command. If you do decide you want locate to run regularly, execute `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` to load its launchd job for regular re-indexing.

Comment: That last part is right from the uninitialized `locate` help message, so it's recommended by Apple.

Answer (score 4):

One can get locate to search almost everywhere by modifying `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`.

Change:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
```

to, say,

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "1" ]; then
```

Some reduction in security. Use only on a personal computer.