# Which tool is most flexible for searching my whole system, locate or mdfind?

Tags: mac, perl, osx-mavericks, spotlight, locate

Follow-on to [Spotlight and the locate command don't search *all* folders](https://superuser.com/questions/195425/spotlight-and-the-locate-command-dont-search-all-folders):

The steps mentioned by Gordon Davisson were performed; `.bashrc` was entered in the Spotlight search field, and System and Invisible files were enabled as per the above reference.  The `.bashrc` file didn't show up at all.  The `${HOME}` perm's were changed from `750` to `755` and several hours elapsed, but `.bashrc` still did not show up.

What is required to see `.bashrc` with Spotlight?  How can Spotlight display `.bashrc` everywhere, if at all, to see the most recentt one, as in?:

```
me@My-MacBook-Pro ~
$ locate .bashrc | most_recent_file
/Users/me/.bashrc
```

(`most_recent_file` is a Perl script which stat's each file in a list and prints the name of the newest one):

Note:  The `locate.updatedb` database creation script was changed to allow find to search the `/etc/locate.rc` specified volume(s) as `root` or `nobody`, depending on whether `root` or `daemon` invokes it, as per [What folders are indexed / covered by 'locate'](https://superuser.com/questions/237014/what-folders-are-indexed-covered-by-locate)).  The logic is tricky, so here's the comment for the updated `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`:

```
# Modify test for expected invocations by either daemon (id=1) or root (id=0);
# if invoked as root, skip test section and search filesystems as root as per
# /etc/locate.rc, a possible security risk if /etc/locate.rc is not tailored
# for production use.  Invoked as daemon, we "spawn" ourselves as nobody to
# gain nobody's filesystem visability, rather than daemon's.
#if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
if [ "$(id -u)" = "1" ]; then
```

---

Here is the Perl source for the `most_recent_file.pl` script.  We have a symbolic link `most_recent_file` in our search paths.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wnl
# From pathname inputs, emits name of one most recently modified
# Gives correct answer where pipelines of this form may not:
#   find . -print | xargs ls –lrdt | tail -1

# NOTE: Use find or locate to provide input, or ls -d dir/*,
# but *not* simply "ls dir" (dir won't be present in pathname)

# Sample invocations:
#      locate '*.c' | most_recent_file
#      ls -d /etc/* | most_recent_file
#      find /local -name 'somescript' | most_recent_file
#      most_recent_file < filelist

BEGIN {
    $newest = 0;    # initialize modification-time reference point
    $name   = "";
}

# Get file's numeric modification time; 10th value from stat
$mtime = ( stat $_ )[9];    # indexing into output of stat
if ( $mtime > $newest ) {   # if True, current file is newest yet seen

    # Remember mod-time for comparison to others,
    # and remember filename for final report
    $newest = $mtime;
    $name   = $_;
}

END {
    print $name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to get the Finder's spotlight search to list .bashrc either (perhaps it's finding it, but not displaying because it's invisible?). But the command-line interface to spotlight... well, it can be convinced to show it. This works:

```
$ mdfind kMDItemFSName = ".bashrc"
/Users/gordon/.bashrc
```

But for some reason the `-name` option doesn't show it:

```
$ mdfind -name ".bashrc"
$
```

...so I don't completely trust this to find what I think it should.

Comment: I changed the Finder attribute AppleShowAllFiles to true.  I also set the spotlight Kind attribute File visibility to Visible or invisible.  Neither of these yield a visible invisible file from spotlight like .bashrc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on macOS Sierra (10.12) anymore.